# fitted probabilities error numerically 0 or 1

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm

I tried to construct a generalized linear model in R.

I receive the following output below with the error "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred". I am wondering is this due to complete separation?
My intercepts and standard errors are not very large and I am wondering is this error due to something else?

```
best <- glm(y ~ p1 + p2 + p3, family = binomial)
```

```
glm.best: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is an *error*?

Comment: @smci- Could you reopen the question and comment on if you think it is a problem of complete separation or if it is actually OK?

Comment: This does **not** look like a complete separation problem. Estimates are not especially large in magnitude (`max(abs(beta))` is less than 2; values of e.g. 8 or higher start to indicate problems) and the standard errors are also reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the error occurs when there is a matter with separation.
To overcome this issue you can use Firth's method. In R Firth's method is implemented in the `logistf` package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logistf/logistf.pdf#Rfn.logistf