# How to fix fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred warning in R

Tags: r

Why am I getting this warning when running my GLM?
pcurv is squared

“glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred”

```
>summary(df.1)
 lon              lat           Roughness           Pcurv         
 Min.   :-71.00   Min.   :-29.98   Min.   :-0.7575   Min.   :-6.62627  
 1st Qu.:-68.70   1st Qu.:-23.90   1st Qu.:-0.7048   1st Qu.:-0.08573  
 Median :-67.34   Median :-19.13   Median :-0.4133   Median : 0.28108  
 Mean   :-66.62   Mean   :-20.71   Mean   : 0.0000   Mean   : 0.00000  
 3rd Qu.:-65.11   3rd Qu.:-17.45   3rd Qu.: 0.4076   3rd Qu.: 0.32911  
 Max.   :-60.15   Max.   :-14.07   Max.   : 4.7961   Max.   : 6.09728  
 Mean.MIN.Temp     Mean.MAX.Temp     Precipitation          pres    
 Min.   :-1.7400   Min.   :-1.9045   Min.   :-0.8101   Min.   :0.0  
 1st Qu.:-0.7141   1st Qu.:-0.7716   1st Qu.:-0.6943   1st Qu.:0.0  
 Median :-0.4810   Median :-0.3799   Median :-0.4338   Median :0.5  
 Mean   : 0.0000   Mean   : 0.0000   Mean   : 0.0000   Mean   :0.5  
 3rd Qu.: 1.0841   3rd Qu.: 1.0467   3rd Qu.: 0.5794   3rd Qu.:1.0  
 Max.   : 1.7223   Max.   : 1.8859   Max.   : 4.3427   Max.   :1.0  
      grp   
 Min.   :1  
 1st Qu.:2  
 Median :3  
 Mean   :3  
 3rd Qu.:4  
 Max.   :5
```

My model code:

```
mdl.glm <- glm(pres~Roughness+Pcurv*I(Pcurv^2)+Mean.MIN.Temp+Mean.MAX.Temp, family=binomial(link=logit), data=subset(df.1,grp!=1))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning means that when R is computing probabilities internally, as part of the fitting process, they sometimes "underflow/overflow" - that is, they're so close to 0 or 1 that they can't be distinguished from them when using R's standard 64-bit floating-point precision (e.g. values less than about 1e-308 or greater than about 1-1e-16).

There's not much you can do about this, it usually has to do with the structure of your data. You *may* be able to improve the numerical stability of fitting and avoid the warning by the following two general strategies:

- center and scale all of your continuous variables (e.g. using the `scale()` function). (This will change the numerical values of your coefficients, but not their p-values [except for the intercept], and won't affect the overall fit of the model (R^2, predictions, etc.) at all.)
- use an orthogonal polynomial `poly(Pcurv,2)` rather than the "raw" quadratic `Pcurv + I(Pcurv^2)`. (This will change these two parameters and their p-values etc. but again won't affect the overall fit of the model.)

If you can't make the warning go away, I would check the following issues carefully:

- do you have symptoms of [complete separation](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/), i.e. large (absolute) parameter values (e.g. `|beta|>8`) and possibly ridiculously large standard errors/p-values? See e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340674/how-can-a-se-be-above-1000-in-a-multilevel-logistic-regression/18341453#18341453), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67338560/zeroinfl-model-warning-message-in-sqrtdiagobjectvcov-nans-produced/67338935#67338935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412064/fitted-probabilities-error-numerically-0-or-1) for suggestions on what to do about it (e.g. replace Wald tests with likelihood ratio tests; Firth regression via `brglm2`; Bayesian models with regularizing priors)
- Do your fits generally make sense, i.e. diagnostics look OK (e.g. see `DHARMa` package), predicted values are sensible? (Of course this is something you should *always* check, but do it extra-carefully)

After that, ignore the warnings and move on with your analysis.